# How to write a functional test for sending email in PHP?

Tags: php, unit-testing, functional-testing, simpletest

My application sends reminder emails, so I am writing a test to make sure that they are sent.

I haven't chosen a testing framework yet, but am considering SimpleTest. I don't think I can use PHPUnit because I do not have access to install anything on the Dev server.

Is it easy to do this in SimpleTest? Should I use SimpleTest at all?

Working in PHP 5.2.8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SimpleMail](http://www.curioussymbols.com/simplemail/) and [Fakemail](http://www.lastcraft.com/fakemail.php) might help you